# VS Code C++ issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, tdm-gcc

I tried to compile a cpp file using VScode, but I have got an issue. The tdm-gcc have already added to environment variable. I tried to reboot my computer but it didn't work. Here is the error.

error:

```
/usr/bin/bash: D:TDM-GCC-64bing++.exe: command not found
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 127
```

Comment: You must ensure your Windows System PATH has the full path to your MinGW install directory, for example `c:\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin`

Comment: I have added `D:\TDM-GCC-64\bin` to the system path, isn't it correct?

Comment: Q: Do you have `TDM-GCC-64bing++.exe` in your `D:\TDM-GCC-64\bin` folder?  Q: Why does the error say `D:TDM-GCC-64bing++.exe` if your %PATH% has `D:\TDM-GCC-64\bin`?  Where is "D:\" coming from?

Comment: I just have g++.exe in the bin folder

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the exact same problem as yours and I think I found a fix.

You probably have Git Bash as your default integrated shell in VSCode in Windows. As the shell parses the path it removes the slashes /. To fix it, you should surround any path with `\"` that is found in your `tasks.json`. This forces the shell to interpret the path correctly. Attached is the args of my tasks.json. Hope this helped.

```
"args": [
            "-g",
            "-Wl,--stack,256000000",
            "-Wl,--heap,256000000",
            "\"${file}\"",
            "-o",
            "\"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe\"",
            "-std=c++11",
            "-O2",
        ],
```